# Is there way to write a unit test for javascript function that calls an html element an does something with it?

Tags: javascript, html, unit-testing, jestjs, mocha.js

I have a function like this:

```
function modaldisplayer(){
   $('.mymodal').modal('show');
   return 'success';
}
```

Also, I have a function foo which contains modaldisplayer(); in it. I'm using mocha, jest and chai as framework. How can I unit test function foo? Mocha is not seeing .modal('show') as a function.

Answer (score 0):

You should look what a changes `$('.mymodal').modal('show');` do in DOM tree.  Most likely it takes some elements and toggle some CSS-classes.

Then your testing code can just check this elements and classes like this

```js
expect($('some modal element').hasClass('e.g modal-visible')).toBeTrue();
```